# How do I link a TEdit with another TEdit?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm working on a small Delphi project. I'm trying to link an `TEdit` with another `TEdit`.

When the user types his username and password and logs in, the username should show up in the next Form. I've created a `TEdit` on the next Form, but I don't know to link it.

Can someone please help me?

I'm using Delphi 10.4!

Comment: http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+I+Foundations/

Answer (score 3):

Well... you actually *can* link one `TEdit` to another `TEdit` (or, for that matter, any other component/control/property to any other component/control/property), but you will need to use [**LiveBinding**](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio), or [**kbmMW SmartBinding**](https://components4developers.blog/tag/smart-binding/).

In kbmMW SmartBinding, you can do it in a couple of ways. In code:

```
Binding.Bind(Edit1,'Text',Edit2,'Text');
```

One way binding. If you change `Edit1.Text` somehow (by typing or by code), `Edit2.Text` will automatically be updated. But, if you change `Edit2.Text`, `Edit1.Text` will not change.

```
Binding.Bind(Edit1,'Text',Edit2,'Text',[mwboTwoWay]);
```

Two way binding. If you change either `Edit1` or `Edit2`'s `Text` property, the other will also be changed.

Or, you can do it at design-time by setting the `Edit1.Text` property to:

```
{Edit2.Text, twoWay:true}
```

And then call `Binding.AutoBind(Self)` in the Form's `OnCreate` event handler.

kbmMW SmartBinding is included in kbmMW Community Edition for Delphi 10.4 Sydney, which is freely available for download at https://portal.components4developers.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't *link* `TEdit` controls together. What you need to do is when the user logs in, read the 1st `TEdit`'s `Text` property and save it to a `String`, then when the next Form is shown, assign that `String` to the 2nd `TEdit`'s `Text` property.

For example:

```pascal
user: String;
...
user := Form1.UserEdit.Text;
...
Form2.UserEdit.Text := user;
```

Comment: How do i do that? please help i really need it!

Comment: @Franklin Really? Working with variables and reading/writing property values are very basic foundation skills in Delphi. If you don't understand how to do this, I suggest you focus on building up those skills first before working with GUIs. In any case, I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: god bless you! i'm doing my best! i'll get there one day! don't worry! i promise!

Comment: Sir can you please tell from where do i start? show me the right way please!!!

Comment: @Franklin: Not to be rude or anything, but the "right way" is *definitely* to buy (or find) a good introductory book about Delphi programming. That is by far the best way to properly learn everything you need to know.